# Web Requests in UWP Apps

Tags: javascript, vb.net, windows, windows-store-apps, uwp

I am new to developing apps for the Universal Windows Platform, and am unsure on how to perform HTTP Requests.

Could someone post an example of how to perform a basic GET request to a URI in both VB.Net and JavaScript in UWP apps? This will help me to understand the basic mechanics of performing web requests.

Thanks.

Comment: Googling "example of how to perform a basic GET request to a URI" gives lots of tutorials of various lengths.  This site is for answering questions when you've tried doing things and are having trouble making them work.  Good luck.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation, there you can see the behaviour of that component

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient

Take a look on this example:

```
    public async Task DoRequest()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://wwww.bing.com");
    }
```